# "Leave for <time>"

Tags: expressions, time

What is the meaning of the following?

> You have to leave for six thirty.

(p.m. implied)

Does it mean you have to leave for your destination at 6:30 p.m.? Or does it mean that you have arrive at your destination by 6:30 p.m?

Comment: I've never heard that expression in my life.  I usually hear _leave at <time>_ or _leave by <time>_.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing this with 'You need to arrive for 7.30'?

Comment: What @Code Maverick said. If someone *did* say that to me, I'd assume they meant *...leave sufficiently early that you'll **arrive** by six thirty*. But obviously I'd ask for clarification - it would be a major disaster to be up and about anywhere *near* "zero dark thirty" and either ***still*** be late, or discover you'd got up significantly earlier than was actually necessary.

Comment: It was actually said to me. It could be a colloquialism particular to the speaker's ethnic group. My interpretation was that they wanted me to leave BEfore 6:30p.m. - if you leave any time before 6:30p.m., you will be on time. They actually meant I needed to arrive at 6:30p.m. What was omitted is was "to get there" between leave and for.

Comment: Is it possible you misheard "for *a* 6:30"? That's a common elision in business meaning "for a 6:30 appointment".

Comment: it might be to "leave for **the** 6:30", as in a train or bus that leaves at that time

Comment: I'm curious as to where the speaker is from, since so many of you seem to find it strange, while to me (Northern Irish childhood, Dublin adult life) it's perfectly common and I would have thought it standard.

Comment: Please provide full context and cite the source.

Comment: @Kris. Source: Personal conversations, 1976-2014. Precisely why I just asked the querent where the speaker was from, as it's news to me that this isn't common.

Comment: @JonHanna The comment above was at the OP!

Comment: @Kris got you. It is though an admitted failing in my answer that I can't cite beyond pers. conv.

Comment: @JonHanna: My understanding is that the meaning of **6:30** depends on nationality. For Brits, it means that time in the morning when those numbers are displayed on digital timepieces. For the Irish, it means early in the morning. For the Spanish, it means *possibly* tomorrow morning (but maybe later).

Comment: @JonHanna You don't seem to have, though. I was asking the OP, where they heard/read this, what was the full context, and the works.

Comment: Nope, the speakers agrees with what I heard, and definitely intended "be there at 6:30pm". Speaker was Canadian of Ukrainian/Irish ancestry (a few generations removed). There is some odd colloquialisms that come out of the Ukrainian side: Open/close the light. Borrow me a pencil. Reach me the glass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now curious (for I, too, would have assumed it signified an arrival time), I googled "leave for 6:30" and "leave for 7:30" until I got at least 20 examples, omitting hits such as "some may leave for 7:30 game") and found all but one meant departure times. This also included train departure times!

By far (obviously) were statements like this one:

> It's arrived, our first day of Westfield ownership, and with a 160 mile trip each way ahead of us we are up at 6, aiming to **leave for 6:30.**

Answer (score 0):

It means they had to leave in such a time as would allow them to arrive at their destination at six-thirty. So if they reckoned they were about 20 minutes away from where they had to be at 6:30, they should leave at 6:10 at the very latest, and aim to have left a bit earlier still, to allow for delays and miscalculation.

Indeed, it's in planning that one would be particularly likely to use it, as one slots in other tasks and chores into ones mental schedule.

I'm curious to read in the comments that it's unknown to many; it's a common expression to my ear, and I thought it was standard (if informal).

Comment: Never heard of it!

Comment: I do not normally do this, but may I ask you to cite references to back up your position (Irish references are fine), because I went in thinking the same thing, only to find I was wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: @Susan. No, I'm answering purely from my own use, and stating it as such; not as good an answer as one that can cite (I'm well aware that people do not speak the language they think they speak), but an answer, and honest about where it lacks. If I did have something I could cite, I certainly would (and certainly will if I find something).